# Is there a way to prevent bean overriding with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

With Spring's [AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.html), I am able to force Spring to fail if there is a conflict in Bean IDs or circular references by setting a couple of flags and refreshing the context like so:

```
AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext refreshableContext;
...
refreshableContext.setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding(false);
refreshableContext.setAllowCircularReferences(false);
refreshableContext.refresh();
```

However, Spring Boot returns a [ConfigurableApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html) which is not an instance of AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext and does not appear to have any means to prevent bean definition overriding or circular references.

Does anyone know of a way and have an example of how to prevent these types of conflicts?

For context, this is for a large project that has a mix of annotated and xml defined beans. The version of Spring Boot used is 1.3.1.RELEASE. There have been some cases where folks added duplicate bean definitions in the xml, but the application started up fine and wasn't immediately apparent the original bean was overridden until run-time issues started occurring.

The goal here is to prevent the application from event starting up if such a conflict occurs. From various forums I know Spring IDE can detect these, but the desire is to enforce this in the CI build which is a stronger safety net.

After some searching, I can't find any support for this in the context that Sprint Boot returns. If this can't be done through the context, is there a different solution available?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Primary is your friend. And /@Resource... Primary and Resource -_-

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think that will work across the application context regardless if the bean comes from xml vs java. I will read up on the Javadocs for those to see when I get back to my desk.

Comment: it will catch bean by id regardless where it's coming from. Also Primary goes first.

Comment: ok, did you try casting? what Spring return is an interface which AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext does implement, so it's possible it's same object

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use an initializer when building your Spring Boot app:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootApp {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(SpringBootApp.class)
            .initializers(new ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericApplicationContext>() {
                @Override
                public void initialize(GenericApplicationContext applicationContext) {
                    applicationContext.setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding(false);
                }
            })
        .run(args);

    }
}
```

Or with java 8:

```
new SpringApplicationBuilder(SpringBootApp.class)
    .initializers((GenericApplicationContext c) -> c.setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding(false) )
    .run(args);
```

Comment: This implementation looks like it is along the lines of what I am looking for. Trying it out and if all works great this will be the accepted answer with an up-vote.

Comment: This solution works and I have been able to resolve been definition conflicts successfully in my Spring Boot application. Thanks for the answer.

On a side note, it now appears that I have a failure coming from the Spring Boot embedded web application context now when bean definition overriding is disable. I'm going to dig into this new issue further now and might have a new question to ask on this new issue sometime in the near future.

Comment: Did you figure out the second failure that was coming from the Spring Boot embedded web application context? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 8):

add below into your application.yml

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding: false
```